# Replace potentiometer with resistor

Tags: ac, potentiometer, triac, dimmer

Can I replace the potentiometer in this AC dimmer circuit with a fixed resistor so that I can get a permanent dim setting?. If yes then how.

[image]

Components in this circuit are
The parts used are

WH149-500k potentiometer 
DB3 bidirectional diode 
2k resistance 0.25W
MAC97A6 
104 630V CBB capacitor

Edit.
here is the picture of the pcb kit. The pot has 4 legs??
[image]

Edit.
I'm adding another circuit which should be clearer.
[image]

Comment: Sure, set the pot where you want, remove it from the circuit, measure its resistance, replace with closest standard value resistor.

Comment: But what should I do with the third leg of the pot?

Comment: You have to measure the pot from the wiper to the right end as shown in your schematic.  Then the fixed resistor goes between the triac and the right side connection.  you don't need the wiper connection, but it's already connected to the triac end anyway.

Comment: ok, I can measure the resistance part but the pot has 4 legs. I've added a new picture. Also here is the product information page with more pictures [link](https://store.electronicsproject.org/product/new-100w-dimmer-module-with-switch-speed-regulation-module-diy-kit-components/)

Comment: A pot typically has 3 terminals.  I can't tell what your fourth terminal is.  You have to figure out which terminals correspond to the 3 points shown in the schematic and measure and wire accordingly.

Comment: Your link says the pot has a switch. The extra connector probably relates to the switch. You should be able to find a datasheet for the pot that would say.

Comment: Generally you can, and others are showing you the way, but don't make the permanent dim level too low or it may not start. This "snap on" effect is a disadvantage of these really simple diac-triac dimmer circuits.

Comment: @Matt  Ok, now I get it, I've updated with a new diagram which should explain more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to maintain the capability to turn the light fully off you will want to either retain the switch part of the pot *(that is the two terminals that stick out the back of the pot)* then it does not make sense to remove the entire pot.

This portion of the schematic represents the On/Off switch in the POT.

[image]

I did not study the PC board artwork configuration but appears that the side of the POT switch that is away from the AC Line is internally connected to these terminals of the circuit diagram:

[image]

Comment: I do not want on off function, I want the lamp to always run at 50% dim.  The circle with an an X was the 4th leg?? I thought that symbol represented the lamp.

Comment: Ok I managed to find out another diagram which is more precise. [Here](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1fdJWOFXXXXXPXVXXq6xXFXXXR/221606454/HTB1fdJWOFXXXXXPXVXXq6xXFXXXR.jpg?size=37268&height=525&width=800&hash=ce4be9d8dcec436d1aa10de5fddfb97c) it is, I think it shows the switch.